# BEM naming for a container div?

Tags: html, css, bem

I'm new to BEM naming convention. From the tutorials I've watched, the Block part seems to be the "Wrapper" which contains Elements. My question is how does BEM work with Containers which cover an entire section of a page? Is it fine to still call them "container"?

My additional question is what if I have two web pages with a different width for Container, say for Login and Main page, is it fine to name them login-container and main-container respectively? Or should I add a name to act as a Modifier?

Here's a basic structure:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="card">
<img class="card__image" src="pic.jpg" alt="pic">
<h2 class="card__header">This is a card</h2>
</div>

<div class="card">
<img class="card__image" src="pic.jpg" alt="pic">
<h2 class="card__header">This is a card</h2>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container` should be something like utility classes, so I would name it `.u-container`.

I think this article could say something about:

https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/when-and-when-not-to-use-utility-classes-with-bem/

Comment: That article is very helpful. I just have a follow up question. In BEM, underscores and dashes have meaning as it could be a block, element, or modifier. Is adding ".u-" at the beginning of a class a part of naming convention of utility classes?

Comment: Yes, `.u-` it means utility classes, so if you need this class you need to start name with `.u-` :)